# C++ Circular #include where forward declaration is not fix

Tags: c++, c++11, include, circular-dependency

I am aware how to solve basic circular dependency example, with two classes, where each needs to know that the other one exists.
However, I am now in situation, where the example is more complicated, and forward declaration is not something, that can fix that issue.

Consider these three files

```
// my_thread.hpp
template<typename Function> class my_thread;

template<typename Return, typename... Input>
struct my_thread<Return(Input...)>
{
    void somefunction() { thread_manager::static_function(); }
}
```

---

```
// thread_manager.hpp
struct thread_manager
{
    static void static_function() { }
    std::list<some_class::thread_type> threads;
}
```

---

```
// some_class.hpp
struct some_class
{
    using thread_type = my_thread<int(some_class*)>
}
```

Now, obviously `my_thread.hpp` requires whole `thread_manager` (or at least it's function?). `thread_manager` requires `using` directive from `some_class` and `some_class` is dependent on `my_thread`. Since STL containers require complete type template parameters, I can't forward declare `my_thread`. I can not even put out definition of `my_thread<T>::somefunction()`, since it's template function and requires to be placed in header.
My question is, how do I resolve this circular dependency?

And funny thing, MSVC does not require `#include "thread_manager" in`my_thread.hpp`for some reason. I don't know how it knows about`thread_manager`.

Comment: then why do you place the definition of `somefunction` before you declare `thread_manager` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It's circular dependency, both files require each other as include. And `my_thread<T>::somefunction()` is template and has to be in header.

Comment: put them in a single header then (along with required definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to tackle this would be to inject thread manager as a template parameter:

```
// my_thread.hpp
template<typename ThreadManager, typename Function> class my_thread;

template<typename ThreadManager, typename Return, typename... Input>
struct my_thread<ThreadManager, Return(Input...)>
{
    void somefunction() { ThreadManager::static_function(); }
}
```

Your `some_class` has to pass the thread manager in, but it does not know anything about the thread manager, so you have to inject the thread manager into `some_class` too:

```
// some_class.hpp
template<typename ThreadManager>
struct some_class
{
    using thread_type = my_thread<ThreadManager, int(some_class*)>;
};
```

Finally, the thread manager is in the position to inject itself into `some_class`:

```
// thread_manager.hpp
struct thread_manager
{
    static void static_function() { }
    std::list<my_thread<thread_manager, int(int)>> threads;
}
```

With this structure nothing directly depends on a thread manager any more.

As an aside, you might want to use your `some_class` in some single threaded context. In that case, you can create a dummy `ThreadManager` that provides the same interface as your `thread_manager` but does nothing, and set this class as a default template parameter.

Comment: Dependency injection will propagate up to the highest level class, so you'll have to inject `thread_manager` into `some_class`. Give me a sec

Comment: It would be nice if I could just forward declare `thread_manager::static_function` without having to do whole `#include`

Comment: It would, but you can't. Dependency injection looks messy at first, but it is great: now your code is testable :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <list>

// my_thread.hpp
template<typename Function> class my_thread;

// thread_manager.hpp
struct thread_manager
{
    static void static_function() { }
    std::list<my_thread<int(int)>> threads;
} ;

template<typename Return, typename... Input>
struct my_thread<Return(Input...)>
{
    void somefunction() { thread_manager::static_function(); }
} ;
```

Another variant: leave the declaration of somefunction in the Template
and implement it in a separate file.

Comment: AFAIK, template functions definitions should be in same (header) file as hte class is defined.

Comment: _"... and implement it in a separate file."_ [Nope!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)